# How to approach and understand a math related DSA question

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, modulo, number-theory

I found this question online and I really have no idea what the question is even asking. I would really appreciate some help in first understanding the question, and a solution if possible. Thanks!

> To see if a number is divisible by 3, you need to add up the digits of its decimal notation, and check if the sum is divisible by 3.
> To see if a number is divisible by 11, you need to split its decimal notation into pairs of digits (starting from the right end), add up corresponding numbers and check if the sum is divisible by 11.
>
> For any prime p (except for 2 and 5) there exists an integer r such that a similar divisibility test exists: to check if a number is divisible by p, you need to split its decimal notation into r-tuples of digits (starting from the right end), add up these r-tuples and check whether their sum is divisible by p.
>
> Given a prime int p, find the minimal r for which such divisibility test is valid and output it.
>
> The input consists of a single integer p - a prime between 3 and 999983, inclusive, not equal to 5.
>
> Example
>
> input
>
> 3
>
> output
>
> 1
>
> input
>
> 11
>
> output
>
> 2

Comment: They're asking for two things: 1) figure out a mathematical way of expressing the relation expounded on in terms of p and r, and then 2) write a program to find the minimal r for the provided p.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a **very cool problem**! It uses modular arithmetic and some basic number theory to devise the solution.

Let's say we have `p = 11`. What divisibility rule applies here? How many digits at once do we need to take, to have a divisibility rule?

Well, let's try a single digit at a time. That would mean, that if we have `121` and we sum its digits `1 + 2 + 1`, then we get `4`. However we see, that although `121` is divisible by `11`, `4` isn't and so the rule doesn't work.

What if we take two digits at a time? With `121` we get `1 + 21 = 22`. We see that `22` **IS** divisible by `11`, so the rule might work here. And in fact, it does. For `p = 11`, we have `r = 2`.

This requires a bit of intuition which I am unable to convey in text (I really have tried) but it can be proven that for a given prime `p` other than `2` and `5`, the divisibility rule works for tuples of digits of length `r` if and only if the number `99...9` (with `r` nines) is divisible by `p`. And indeed, for `p = 3` we have `9 % 3 = 0`, while for `p = 11` we have `9 % 11 = 9` (this is bad) and `99 % 11 = 0` (this is what we want).

If we want to find such an `r`, we start with `r = 1`. We check if `9` is divisible by `p`. If it is, then we found the `r`. Otherwise, we go further and we check if `99` is divisible by `p`. If it is, then we return `r = 2`. Then, we check if `999` is divisible by `p` and if so, return `r = 3` and so on. However, the `99...9` numbers can get very large. Thankfully, to check divisibility by `p` we only need to store the remainder modulo `p`, which we know is small (at least smaller than `999983`). So the code in C++ would look something like this:

```cpp
int r(int p) {
  int result = 1;
  int remainder = 9 % p;
  while (remainder != 0) {
    remainder = (remainder * 10 + 9) % p;
    result++;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: "This requires a bit of intuition which I am unable to convey in text..." The number 99..9 is divisible by p if and only if 100..0 is congruent to 1 mod p. Since the multiplicative group of Z/pZ is finite, repeated multiplication by 10 will eventually take you to 1. This assumes that 10 is not congruent to 0 mod p, which is true for primes that are not factors of 10 (i.e. not 2 or 5).

Comment: That's a good explanation! Albeit I'd argue it isn't in any way an "intuitive" explanation.

Comment: @Maurycyt I added an answer that tries to explain that from scratch. I don't know how readable it is if you don't know it. But it explains a stronger result - namely why you only need consider powers that divide `p-1`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I truly appreciate this insightful answer.

Comment: If you appreciate it, upvote it. If it solved your question, accept it with the green tick. ;) Welcome to stack overflow.

Comment: Awesome, I accepted it. Do you have any good resources that you would recommend for me so I could study these sort of problems more in depth?

Comment: [CP Algorithms](https://cp-algorithms.com/) contains a lot of articles about all sorts of topics, beginner and advanced. You should also visit [CodeForces](https://codeforces.com/) for some practical training. You can ask around more over there, to see which resources people use. I personally collected my knowledge from local events like classes at school. Perhaps you could see if some high school in your area organises such classes, preferable open to people from outside the school.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea how they expect a random programmer with no background to figure out the answer from this.

But here is the brief introduction to modulo arithmetic that should make this doable.

In programming, `n % k` is the modulo operator.  It refers to taking the remainder of `n / k`.  It satisfies the following two important properties:

```
(n + m) % k = ((n % k) + (m % k)) % k
(n * m) % k = ((n % k) * (m % k)) % k
```

Because of this, for any `k` we can think of all numbers with the same remainder as somehow being the same.  The result is something called "the integers modulo `k`".  And it satisfies most of the rules of algebra that you're used to.  You have the associative property, the commutative property, distributive law, addition by 0, and multiplication by 1.

However if `k` is a composite number like `10`, you have the unfortunate fact that `2 * 5 = 10` which means that modulo `10`, `2 * 5 = 0`.  That's kind of a problem for division.

BUT if `k = p`, a prime, then things become massively easier.  If `(a*m) % p = (b*m) % p` then `((a-b) * m) % p = 0` so `(a-b) * m` is divisible by `p`. And therefore either `(a-b)` or `m` is divisible by `p`.

For any non-zero remainder `m`, let's look at the sequence `m % p, m^2 % p, m^3 % p, ...`.  This sequence is infinitely long and can only take on `p` values.  So we must have a repeat where, `a < b` and `m^a % p = m^b %p`.  So `(1 * m^a) % p = (m^(b-a) * m^a) % p`.  Since `m` doesn't divide `p`, `m^a` doesn't either, and therefore `m^(b-a) % p = 1`.  Furthermore `m^(b-a-1) % p` acts just like `m^(-1) = 1/m`.  (If you take enough math, you'll find that the non-zero remainders under multiplication is a finite group, and all the remainders forms a field.  But let's ignore that.)

(I'm going to drop the `% p` everywhere.  Just assume it is there in any calculation.)

Now let's let `a` be the smallest positive number such that `m^a = 1`.  Then `1, m, m^2, ..., m^(a-1)` forms a cycle of length `a`.  For any `n` in `1, ..., p-1` we can form a cycle (possibly the same, possibly different) `n, n*m, n*m^2, ..., n*m^(a-1)`.  It can be shown that these cycles partition `1, 2, ..., p-1` where every number is in a cycle, and each cycle has length `a`.  THEREFORE, `a` divides `p-1`.  As a side note, since `a` divides `p-1`, we easily get [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) that `m^(p-1)` has remainder `1` and therefore `m^p = m`.

OK, enough theory.  Now to your problem.  Suppose we have a base `b = 10^i`.  The primality test that they are discussing is that `a_0 + a_1 * b + a_2 * b^2 + a_k * b^k` is divisible by a prime `p` if and only if `a_0 + a_1 + ... + a_k` is divisible by `p`.  Looking at `(p-1) + b`, this can only happen if `b % p` is 1.  And if `b % p` is 1, then in modulo arithmetic `b` to any power is `1`, and the test works.

So we're looking for the smallest `i` such that `10^i % p` is `1`.  From what I showed above, `i` always exists, and divides `p-1`.  So you just need to factor `p-1`, and try `10` to each power until you find the smallest `i` that works.

Note that you should `% p` at every step you can to keep those powers from getting too big.  And with repeated squaring you can speed up the calculation.  So, for example, calculating `10^20 % p` could be done by calculating each of the following in turn.

```
10 % p
10^2 % p
10^4 % p
10^5 % p
10^10 % p
10^20 % p
```

Comment: This is impressive. I should steal this for my algorithmic masterclass. I wasn't expecting this, but this is a really cool problem combining the Sieve of Eratosthenes, and Fermat's little theorem (and NOT for finding the modular inverse). I wonder if finding the "interesting" divisors of `p-1` can be optimised. Apparently the number of divisors in practice bound by `n^(1/3)` [as seen in this CF blog](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/14463). So it seems like this method has complexity of at most (and this is a crude estimate) O(p^(1/3)log(p)) (if you already have the factorisation).

Comment: @Maurycyt You can actually start with `best = p-1` and for each prime `q` in the prime factorization of `p-1`, you can test `best/q` to see if that works.  Each test takes `O(log(p))` steps and you need at most `O(log(p))` tests for `O(log(p)^2)`.  The real work is now in the factorization.

Comment: If multiple divisors `q` of `best` work, how do I know which one to pick? Can this be solved greedily? So let's pretend that `p = 13`, then we start with `best = 12`. We all know that `12 = 2 * 2 * 3` so one possible `q` will be `2` and the other will be `3`. Say that both `best / 2` and `best / 3` work. Which one do I "descend to"? What if `best / 2 / 2` is actually the best? This is a simple example but more complicated ones could be found. I have a feeling that the answer might be `GCD(best / q^k)` taken over all `q` and `k` that "work".

Comment: @Maurycyt The shortest repeat will be the GCD of all other repeats. So yes, you can solve it greedily.  Incidentally for 13 the answer is 6.

Answer (score 0):

This is an almost direct application of [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

First, you have to reformulate the *"split decimal notation into tuples [...]"*-condition into something you can work with:

> to check if a number is divisible by p, you need to split its decimal notation into r-tuples of digits (starting from the right end), add up these r-tuples and check whether their sum is divisible by p

When you translate it from prose into a formula, what it essentially says is that you want

[image]

for any choice of *"r-tuples of digits"* `b_i` from `{ 0, ..., 10^r - 1 }` (with only finitely many `b_i` being non-zero).

Taking `b_1 = 1` and all other `b_i = 0`, it's easy to see that it is necessary that

[image]

It's even easier to see that this is also sufficient (all `10^ri` on the left hand side simply transform into factor `1` that does nothing).

Now, if `p` is neither `2` nor `5`, then `10` will not be divisible by `p`, so that Fermat's little theorem guarantees us that

[image]

, that is, at least the solution `r = p - 1` exists. This might not be the smallest such `r` though, and [computing the smallest one is hard if you don't have a quantum computer handy](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2180063/232119).

Despite it being hard in general, for very small `p`, you can simply use an algorithm that is linear in `p` (you simply look at the sequence

```
10    mod p 
100   mod p
1000  mod p
10000 mod p
...
```

and stop as soon as you find something that equals `1 mod p`).

Written out as code, for example, in Scala:

```
def blockSize(p: Int, n: Int = 10, r: Int = 1): Int =
  if n % p == 1 then r else blockSize(p, n * 10 % p, r + 1)

println(blockSize(3))  // 1
println(blockSize(11)) // 2
println(blockSize(19)) // 18
```

or in Python:

```
def blockSize(p: int, n: int = 10, r: int = 1) -> int:
  return r if n % p == 1 else blockSize(p, n * 10 % p, r + 1)

print(blockSize(3))  # 1
print(blockSize(11)) # 2
print(blockSize(19)) # 18
```

A wall of numbers, just in case someone else wants to sanity-check alternative approaches:

```
11 -> 2
13 -> 6
17 -> 16
19 -> 18
23 -> 22
29 -> 28
31 -> 15
37 -> 3
41 -> 5
43 -> 21
47 -> 46
53 -> 13
59 -> 58
61 -> 60
67 -> 33
71 -> 35
73 -> 8
79 -> 13
83 -> 41
89 -> 44
97 -> 96
101 -> 4
103 -> 34
107 -> 53
109 -> 108
113 -> 112
127 -> 42
131 -> 130
137 -> 8
139 -> 46
149 -> 148
151 -> 75
157 -> 78
163 -> 81
167 -> 166
173 -> 43
179 -> 178
181 -> 180
191 -> 95
193 -> 192
197 -> 98
199 -> 99
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you andrey tyukin.

Simple terms to remember:

1. When x%y =z then (x%y)%y again =z
2. (X+y)%z == (x%z + y%z)%z
   keep this in mind.

So you break any number into some r digits at a time together. I.e. break 3456733 when r=6 into 3 * 10 power(6 * 1) + 446733 * 10 power(6 * 0).

And you can break 12536382626373 into 12 * 10 power (6 * 2). + 536382 * 10 power (6 * 1) + 626373 * 10 power (6 * 0)

Observe that here r is 6.

So when we say we combine the r digits and sum them together and apply modulo. We are saying we apply modulo to coefficients of above breakdown.

So how come coefficients sum represents whole number’s sum?

When the “10 power (6* anything)” modulo in the above break down becomes 1 then that particular term’s modulo will be equal to the coefficient’s modulo. That means the 10 power (r* anything) is of no effect. You can check why it will have no effect by using the formulas 1&2.

And the other similar terms 10 power (r * anything) also will have modulo as 1. I.e. if you can prove that (10 power r)modulo is 1. Then (10 power r * anything) is also 1.

But the important thing is we should have 10 power (r) equal to 1. Then every 10 power (r * anything) is 1 that leads to modulo of number equal to sum of r digits divided modulo.

Conclusion: find r in (10 power r) such that the given prime number will leave 1 as reminder.

That also mean the smallest 9…..9 which is divisible by given prime number decides r.